# How to pass a variable into a custom tag in Liquid?

Tags: liquid

I have written a custom tag in liquid, and I'd like to pass a variable to it. Liquid tags will turn any parameter into a string.

For example:

```
{% nav page /some/url.html %}
```

Where page is a variable.

Is there a way to get Liquid to treat page as a variable and not a string?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I should mention this question is specifically about Jekyll but applicable to any Liquid custom tag.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919644/using-liquid-variables-inside-of-a-liquid-tag-call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259385/resolve-liquid-variable-inside-liquid-tag

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using Jekyll specifically, you can access the page variable this way:

```
def render(context)
  page_url = context.environments.first["page"]["url"]
```

Comment: OK, I can access a post's liquid hash this way. Is there any way to access the `Post` object from `context`?

Comment: This really should go into Jekyll documentation!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by creating a custom lookup method:

```
def look_up(context, name)
  lookup = context

  name.split(".").each do |value|
    lookup = lookup[value]
  end

  lookup
end
```

To use it, create something like this:

```
def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
  @markup = markup
  super
end

def render(context)
  output = super
  if @markup =~ /([\w]+(\.[\w]+)*)/i
    @myvalue = look_up(context, $1)
  end

  do_something_with(@myvalue)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer the general question and not the part specifically about the page variable, you can also pass the contents of the tag through the Liquid parser again:

```
def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
  @markup = markup
  super
end

def render(context)
  content = Liquid::Template.parse(@markup).render context
end
```