# WordPress' body_class functionality using Jekyll and Liquid Tags

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm not the biggest fan of WordPress, but I think the one thing that WordPress gets right is the `body_class` functionality.

I want to recreate this functionality using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) and [Liquid Tags](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid). I want to be able to make a call like

```
<body class="{% body_class %}">
```

That would automatically generate classes based on:

- Jekyll Template
- Current Post (if any)
- Current Page (if any)
- Current Category (if any)

Examples:

/index.html with default layout would result in

```
<body class="layout-default page-index">
```

/_posts/2012-01-01-my-unique-entry.markdown with blog.html layout would result in

```
<body class="layout-blog post-my-unique-entry">
```

I know I can achieve all this using YAML front matter, but If I can automate this to remove one more repetitious variable, that would be ideal.

From what I've attempted so far, this is the strategy I'm taking:

```
class BodyClassTag < Liquid::Tag

  def initialize(tag_name, name, tokens)
    super tag_name, name, tokens
  end

  def render(context)
    # Build string from Jekyll instance variables possible here?
  end

end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('body_class', BodyClassTag)
```

Any ideas on if this is possible, and what to tie into if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information gleaned from [the answers on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666236/how-to-pass-a-variable-into-a-custom-tag-in-liquid), I was able to come up with a solution that behaves pretty much exactly the way I wanted it to. This is my custom liquid tag. Posting here in case anyone wants to achieve something similar.

```
class BodyClassTag < Liquid::Tag  

  def prefixed_body_class(prefix, id)
    id = id.gsub(/\.\w*?$/, '') # Remove extension from url
    id = id.gsub(/[-\/]/, '_')  # Replace '-' and '/' with underscore
    id = id.gsub(/^_/, '')      # Remove leading '_'

    case prefix
    when "class"
      prefix = ""
    else
      prefix = "#{prefix}_"
    end

    "#{prefix}#{id}"
  end

  def render(context)
    page = context.environments.first["page"]
    classes = []

    %w[class url categories tags layout].each do |prop|
      next unless page.has_key?(prop)
      if page[prop].kind_of?(Array)
        page[prop].each { |proper| classes.push prefixed_body_class(prop, proper) }
      else
        classes.push prefixed_body_class(prop, page[prop])
      end
    end

    classes.join(" ")
  end

end
Liquid::Template.register_tag('body_class', BodyClassTag)
```

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong, but I'm not sure you need to use ruby for all that; for example, the layout,  is available from in the liquid variable `page`.

So in your layout file, you can do this:

```
{% capture layout %}{% if page.layout %}layout-{{ page.layout }}{% endif %}{% endcapture %}

<body class="{{ layout }}">
```

The "unique identifier of pages and posts" is a bit more complex, since there is no such concept in Jekyll. But you can get pretty much the same using `page.url` and replacing slashes by '-'. If you are not seeing a post, then you are seeing a page. So:

```
{% capture id_prefix %}{% if post %}post{% else %}page{% endif %}{% endcapture %}
{% capture id %}{{ id_prefix }}-{{ page.url | replace:'/','-' }}{% endcapture %}

<body class="{{ layout }} {{ id }}">
```

You can calculate category pretty similarly (remember though that a post can have more than one category).

Warning: all the code above has been done from the top of my head, and not tested at all.

Comment: Good idea on using captures. That approach hadn't occurred to me at all. I still like the idea of creating some kind of drop in {% body_class %} tag that will be more portable to move across projects, but if that doesn't pan out, this is definitely worth fleshing out.

Answer (score 1):

This is late based on the fact that I am just now getting into Jekyll but hopefully my solution will be helpful to someone. I used a Front Matter variable along with a simple if statement. So here are the two simple steps using an About page as an example.

In your About page add something like this variable to your Front Matter (you can use any name you would like):

```
body_class: page-about
```

More detailed example:

```
---
title: About
permalink: "/about/"
layout: page
body_class: page-about
---
```

Now add this if statement to your body tag:

```
{% if page.body_class %}class="{{ page.body_class }}"{% endif %}
```

More detailed example:

```
<body {% if page.body_class %}class="{{ page.body_class }}"{% endif %}>
```

If the body_class variable exists, a class is added to the body. If the body_class variable doesn't exist in the page Front Matter, no class is added.

If you would like to add an extra class to a class that already exists in the body, this should work as well (make sure the space exists before :

```
<body class="main{% if page.body_class %} {{ page.body_class }}{% endif %}">
```

I have confirmed this works well for me and hopefully someone else can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to default.html

```
<body class="{{ page.id | remove:'/' }}">
```

Hope this helps out guys,

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to provide multiple styling hooks in decreasing order of specificity, like so:

```
<body class="
{{ post.title | downcase | replace:' ','-' | replace:',','' | strip_html }}
{% if page.category %} category-{{ page.category }}{% endif %}
{% if page.layout-class %} layout-{{ page.layout-class }}{% endif %}
">
```

Which creates an output like:

```
<body class="my-stackoverflow-design category-portfolio layout-category">
```

I'm using a page-layout class in my front-matter as there is currently [a bug in Jekyll that means {{ page.layout }} doesn't work](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1934); it always returns 'default' irrespective of the layout in use.