# using Liquid variables inside of a liquid tag call

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, template-engine, liquid

I made a custom link tag in Liquid and I am trying to be able to pass liquid variables into the call for that tag like so

```
{{ assign id = 'something' }} // this value is actual dynamic while looping through data 
{% link_to article: id, text: 'Click Me!' %} // my custom tag
```

However this results in the article parameter being passed in as 'id' instead of 'something' as per the assign statement above it.

Does anyone know how to pass variables into tag calls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't look like this is possible, my solution was to just pass the variable name in to the tag and grab it out of the context the tag is being rendered in. Like so:

```
{% for article in category.articles %}
  {% link_to variable: article, text: title %}
{% endfor %}
```

in my tag code (condensed):

```
def render(context)
  uri = "article/#{context[@options[:variable]]['id']}"
  "<a href='#{uri}'>#{build_link_text context}</a>"
end
```

Answer (score 11):

I've recently solved this very simply with Jekyll 0.11.2 and Liquid 2.3.0 by passing the *name* of the variable as the tag parameter.

```
{% assign v = 'art' %}
{% link_to_article v %}
```

You can also pass the name of the control var while in a loop, like `article` above.

In `Liquid::Tag.initialize`, `@markup` is the second parameter, the string following the tag name. The assigned variables are available in the top level of the `context`.

```
def render(context)
  "/#{context[@markup.strip]}/"
end
```

This obviously only allows one param to be passed. A more complex solution would parse params like `x: 2, y: 3`.

Answer (score 8):

This solved the case for me `context[@markup.strip]`.

My problem was that i wanted to be able to pass a variable to my custom Liquid tag like this: `{% get_menu main_menu navigation.html settings.theme.id %}`

In order to do this i first split the variable string into different varaibles on every space character.

```
class GetMenu < Liquid::Tag
    include ApplicationHelper
    def initialize(tag_name, variables, tokens)

        @variables = variables.split(" ")

        @menu_object = @variables[0]
        @file_name = @variables[1]
        @theme_id = @variables[2]

        super
    end

    def render(context)

        # This is where i use context[@theme_id.strip] to get the variable of "settings.theme.id"
        content = CodeFile.find_by(hierarchy: 'snippet', name: @file_name.to_s, theme_id: context[@theme_id.strip])

        @menu ||= Menu.find_by_slug(@menu_object)

        context.merge('menu' => @menu)

        Liquid::Template.parse(content.code).render(context)

    end

end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('get_menu', GetMenu)
```

*This is just a more rich example that the answer above by Jonathan Julian

Answer (score 3):

It would be great to have a tag that can be called with literals and variables like

```
{% assign v = 'art' %}
{% link_to_article v %}
```

or

```
{% link_to_article 'art' %}
```

or

```
{% link_to_article "art" %}
```

and also of course

```
{% link_to_article include.article %}
```

In order to so I propose a helper function

```
def get_value(context, expression)
  if (expression[0]=='"' and expression[-1]=='"') or (expression[0]=="'" and expression[-1]=="'")
    # it is a literal
    return expression[1..-2]
  else
    # it is a variable
    lookup_path = expression.split('.')
    result = context
    puts lookup_path
    lookup_path.each do |variable|
      result = result[variable] if result
    end
    return result
  end
end
```

And in the render just call the helper function to get the value of the literal or variable.

```
def render(context)
  v = get_value(context, @markup.strip)
end
```

FYI, the initialiser would look like this:

```
def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
  @markup = markup
  super
end
```

Comment: Can you point me towards a fast truck of implementing your helper function if I only edited liquid on the Shopify platform so far?

Answer (score 0):

This does not strictly answer the question, but it may help others who are new to Liquid (like myself) and try something like this. Instead of implementing a custom *tag*, consider implementing a [custom *filter*](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Programmers#create-your-own-filters) instead. Variables are resolved before they are passed into filters.

Ruby code:

```rb
module MyFilters
  def link_to_article(input, text)
    "<a href='https://example.org/article/#{input}'>#{text}</a>"
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(MyFilters)
```

Liquid template:

```
{% assign id = 'something' %} 
{{ id | link_to_article: 'Click Me!' }}
```

Output:

```html
<a href='https://example.org/article/something'>Click Me!</a>
```

You can also use variables as parameters. So the following would have the same output:

```
{% assign id = 'something' %} 
{% assign text = 'Click Me!' %}
{{ id | link_to_article: text }}
```

And filters can have zero or more (comma-separated) parameters:

```
{{ 'input' | filter_with_zero_parameters }}
{{ 'input' | filter_with_two_parameters: 'parameter 1', 'parameter 2' }}
```