# link_to in liquid template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in Ruby on rails and facing issue while creating link_to using Liquid gem. I want to create a link in the email template like:

```
{{link_to 'Submit', profile_accounts_url(:account_id => account.id)}}
```

However, link is not created in email template. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use liquied before, but you can check the syntax for link_to here.

[using Liquid variables inside of a liquid tag call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919644/using-liquid-variables-inside-of-a-liquid-tag-call)

http://richonrails.com/articles/liquid-templating-engine

However, I think you're using rails' syntax for `link_to` instead of liquid's syntax. Maybe you should just use something like:

```
<%= link_to "Submit", profile_accounts_path(account) %>
```

which will redirect to the show page.

Comment: Hi Adler, thanks for your help. I solved the problem by using this code..<% link = link_to 'Submit', profile_accounts_url(:account_id => @account.id) %>
<%= @template.render('LINK' => link).html_safe %> in html.erb....and by putting this {{LINK}} in my email template