# Jekyll - Pass a jekyll variable to a custom liquid tag

Tags: variables, plugins, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to work out how to pass a Jekyll variable to a liquid tag plugin.
I tried doing this:

```
{% liquidtag {{ variable }} %}
```

But the variable does not get realised and the tag just receives the variable name with the curly brackets: `{{ variable }}`

It also does not get realised when I use: `{% liquidtag {% variable %} %}` - the `{%` before the variable gets included in the string and the `%}` after the variable gets matched with the first `{%` of the liquid tag - the last closing `%}` get's ignored. I.e, this gets passed:
`{% variable`

What I want is for the actual value of the variable to be passed to the tag.

Here's the tag:

```
class CatAbs < Liquid::Tag
        def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
          super
          @text = text
          puts @text
        end
        def render(context)
          return @text.split("-").at(1)
        end
      end
```

And here's how I'm currently referencing the tag:

```
{% for tag in site.categories %} 
<div class="grid grid-pad">
  <a><h2>{% CatAbs {{ tag[0] }} %} »</h2></a>
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using Liquid variables inside of a liquid tag call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919644/using-liquid-variables-inside-of-a-liquid-tag-call)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I finally found the answer. I don't know why it was so difficult for me to find before! Sorry for the duplicate question!
Here's the answer I found:

[using Liquid variables inside of a liquid tag call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919644/using-liquid-variables-inside-of-a-liquid-tag-call?lq=1)

Comment: I found your question DuckDuckGo'ing my question so thanks for the duplicate!