# Use variable inside Liquid tag call instead of string

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, liquid

I have already checked [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919644/using-liquid-variables-inside-of-a-liquid-tag-call) and it doesn't seem to work for my problem. I have issue passing `post.image` variable name to tag `responsive_image`. If I pass string like that `{% responsive_image path: assets/img/ar-7.jpg %}` it works without any issue but I didn't found a way how to pass variable to that. Any ideas?

1) I thought this would work, unfortunately string `post.image` is passed instead of variable. Commented  code is working example that I need to change to responsive image.

```
 {% if post.image %}
  {% responsive_image path: post.image %}
  <!-- <img class="has-ratio" src="{{post.image}}" /> -->
 {% endif %}
```

```
Invalid image path specified: "post.image" 
  Liquid Exception: unable to open image `/Users/.../Documents/Apps/Jekyll/wtc-mbp/post.image': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2881 in .html
```

2) Solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919644/using-liquid-variables-inside-of-a-liquid-tag-call), doesn't work

```
 {% if post.image %}
  {% assign path = post.image %}
  {% responsive_image path %}
 {% endif %}
```

```
Invalid image path specified: nil 
  Liquid Exception: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/566 in .html
```

3) Another idea also doesn't work

```
 {% if post.image %}
  {% assign path = post.image %}
  {% responsive_image path: path %}
 {% endif %}
```

```
Invalid image path specified: "path" 
Liquid Exception: unable to open image `/Users/.../Documents/Apps/Jekyll/wtc-mbp/path': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2881 in .html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Liquid variables, you need to opt for the [`responsive_image_block`](https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/jekyll-responsive-image#liquid-variables-as-attributes) tag instead:

```
{% responsive_image_block %}
  path: {{ post.image }}
{% endresponsive_image_block %}
```